# How to submit a plugin in phonegap site?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I am creating my first application in Phonegap. I have made some plugin like FileOpener, Downloader and stausBarNotification. Plugins are like this:

**FileOpener.js is like this:**

```
cordova.define("cordova/plugin/fileopener",
          function(require, exports, module) {
            var exec = require("cordova/exec");
            var FileOpener = function () {};

        FileOpener.prototype.open = function(url) {
            exec(null, null, "FileOpener", "openFile", [url]);
        };

        var fileOpener = new FileOpener();
            module.exports = fileOpener;

        });
        /**
         * Load Plugin
         */
        if (!window.plugins) {
            window.plugins = {};
        }
        if (!window.plugins.fileOpener) {
            window.plugins.fileOpener = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/fileopener");
        }
```

**Downloader.js** is like this:

```
cordova.define("cordova/plugin/downloader",
  function(require, exports, module) {
    var exec = require("cordova/exec");
    var Downloader = function () {};

Downloader.prototype.downloadFile = function(fileUrl, dirName, fileName, overwrite, win, fail) {
    navigator.notification.alert('url: '+fileUrl+' to dir: '+dirName + ' to file: '+fileName);
    if (overwrite == false)
        overwrite = "false";
    else
        overwrite = "true";
    exec(win, fail, "Downloader", "downloadFile", [ fileUrl, dirName, fileName, overwrite ]);

};
var downloader = new Downloader();
    module.exports = downloader;

});
if (!window.plugins) {
    window.plugins = {};
}
if (!window.plugins.downloader) {
    window.plugins.downloader = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/downloader");
}
```

And I have have made some java file to implement is as well. Now it is running as expected in android device. But now I want a same project for for ios and I want build.phonegap.com will do that for me.

I have include the plugin in **config.xml** like this:

```
<gap:plugin name="FileOpener" value="com.phonegap.plugins.fileOpener.FileOpener"/>  
<gap:plugin name="Downloader" value="com.phonegap.plugins.downloader.Downloader"/>
<gap:plugin name="StatusBarNotification" value="com.phonegap.plugins.statusBarNotification.StatusBarNotification"/>
```

Now where to go from here? I have read some articles which is telling me to submit the plugin to phonegap.com how will i do this? Will the project run same as android device in iPhone? Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to submit your plugin, follow the documentation found at https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins-contributing. Once submitted, it will be reviewed and made available to the public. You can see a list of available plugins at https://build.phonegap.com/plugins